# Why cant I use dots in arrays?

Tags: php, json

I wanted to try something out with an API from a company. I wanted to put their data into my database. But I've run into a problem. The API has one JSON object called "venue.country". But I can't use dots in my array for some reason?

Here is the code:

```
    foreach ($data[1]['hits']['hits'] as $row) {
        $statement->execute(array(
            "name" => $row['fields']['name'][0],
            "date" => $row['fields']['start'][0],
            "lang_long" => "test",
It is this one! -> "country" => $row['fields']['venue.country'][0],
            "genres" => $row['fields']['genres'][0],
            "desc" => $row['fields']['description'][0],
            "logo" => $row['fields']['logo'][0],
            "header_pic" => $row['fields']['header'][0]
        ));
    }
```

\everything else works in the PHP
And here is a piece of the JSON:

```
venue.country: [
"Nederland"
],
```

How can I get this to work? Can I use the "explode" method?

This is the full JSON: 
https://hugo.events/genre/pop/next/200/120

Thanks.

EDIT:
Even with the answer @Prototype Chain gave it is giving me this error: `Notice: Undefined index: venue in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pop.php on line 18`

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP error? What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the output of: `print_r($row);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. After debugging I found that, there is no key/index venue.country for the array elements $data[1]['hits']['hits'][50] and $data[1]['hits']['hits'][51]. Since there is no index, its throwing notice.

You can add @before the variable to suppress the notice or check the condition if the index exixts.

```
"country" => @$row['fields']['venue.country'][0],

"country" => isset($row['fields']['venue.country']) ? $row['fields']['venue.country'][0] : '',
```

// run this code for testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://hugo.events/genre/pop/next/200/100');
$data     = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach ($data[1]['hits']['hits'] as $row) {
   // echo $row['fields']['name'][0].'=>'.@$row['fields']['venue.country'][0].'<br/>';
   $array[]= array(
        "name" => $row['fields']['name'][0],
        "country" => isset($row['fields']['venue.country']) ? $row['fields']['venue.country'][0] : ''
        );
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Comment: When I use your code I still don't get the country in my database

Comment: You mean you are not getting country for all the rows are for few ?

Comment: Im not gettimg them for all the countries

Comment: Its strange. I have added some code in the answer, can you run that code and check if countries are available in output.

Comment: If I try the code you added it doesn't return an error or anything, even tho I  have added an exception handler.

Comment: check if the country is printed for all the array elements.

Comment: Oh I see your new code now. I can add the venue.location tho

Comment: The country is printed in the array

Comment: now check the query. There might be a problem in you query.

Comment: Still nothing happening I've checked everything

Comment: remove/comment this line of code $jsondata = str_replace( "venue.country", "venuecountry", $jsondata );

Answer (score 1):

This code works just fine given your example JSON data:

```
$string = <<<EOT
  {INSERT YOUR JSON STRING HERE}
EOT;

$json = json_decode( $string, true );
echo $json[1]['hits']['hits'][0]['fields']['venue.location'][0] . "\n";
echo $json[1]['hits']['hits'][0]['fields']['venue.location'][1] . "\n";
```

Comment: It gives me a lot of illegal string offsets: https://wtd-server-a1070rik.c9users.io/pop.php Check it out

Comment: Post a bin of the full code that you're using on that pop.php page. That error makes no sense unless you did something like put quotes around the string inside the <<<EOT block.

Comment: I cant use a <<<EOT block. I need to use the url. Else I need to do everything automatic and that is not my aim

Comment: Here you have a ghostbin of the complete pop.php code https://ghostbin.com/paste/ubdjp

Comment: This PHP code works fine, and it's based on your ghostbin with unrelated code removed: https://ghostbin.com/paste/ekcvs

Comment: Thanks! Can you post your code as an answer so I can set it as the answer?

Comment: My code isn't an answer. There was literally nothing wrong with the code that you posted. If it was giving you errors, they were unrelated to dots in the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to debug without seeing the entire contents of the JSON data, however, in the past when I've hard trouble parsing JSON or XML data from a source that formatted it strangely, I found it useful to perform a pre-process str_replace() on the data before I parsed it.

So something like this might work for you:

```
$input = some_function_to_get_string_data_from_api();
$input = str_replace( "venue.country", "venuecountry", $input );
$json  = json_encode( $input );
```

It's not an elegant solution, and it falls apart quickly if you're dealing with lots and lots of fields that need modifying, but if you're only dealing with a single field or two that are giving you trouble, it can be a quick and dirty patch.

Comment: Still the same error. I have changed the code to match to my code

Comment: If you go this route, you would have to also change: $row['fields']['venue.country'][0] to : $row['fields']['venuecountry'][0]

If you're still getting the same error after that change, the it's an error unrelated to a dot in the field name

Comment: Still gives me the same error. I will have to check the API then.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will do the trick..

```
$row['fields']['venue']['country'][0]
```